# A question about input rating of a transistor module

Tags: transistors, datasheet

I'm planning to use [this](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/relay/relay-click-schematic-v100-a.pdf) relay board. It says [here](https://www.mikroe.com/relay-click) on their website the input is 5V.

In my case Vcc is 5V but the input signal to Q1 and Q2  will be 3.3V, so I'm not sure if the input signal to the transistor module is fine with 3.3V.

[Here](https://www.mouser.dk/datasheet/2/916/PDTC114E_SER-2937084.pdf) is the datasheet of the PDTC114EU. Would this module work fine with 3.3V input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relay datasheet says that it wants 40 mA.

The transistor datasheet shows that to get 40 mA, you need an input voltage at 5 V (or even more when at lower temperatures), while 3.3 V gives you only 20 mA:

[image: PDTC114EU on-state input voltage vs. collector current]

And this does not account for the LED current. That board just barely works at 5 V.